# Is there a way to retrieve and compile object text from a shape or connector in a Visio drawing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-visio

[image]I have a diagram with a bunch of numbered connectors. I'd like to be able to easily/quickly create a list of all of the connector numbers in the diagram. Is there a way to do this without inputting equipment data beforehand (e.g. through VBA or python or some built in report feature)?

EDIT: I have added a sample of the type of diagram I'm talking about. Basically I'd like to be able to click a button and get a list that says: 101, 102, 103, 104, 105.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the screenshot about the diagram and the result you want.

Comment: @Lee, I just added a sample diagram. They can get more complicated than that, but that is a basic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomnend check this article - [Listing Connections in Visio 2010](https://bvisual.net/2009/09/16/listing-connections-in-visio-2010/) by [David J Parker](https://www.amazon.com/David-J-Parker/e/B001IR1R9C).
There you can find VBA code.

Comment: This is a great answer. I was able to modify his macro and use Visio.Shape.Text to retrieve the data I was looking for. I would also like to leave a list of Visio.Shape properties here in case someone is trying to retrieve other properties in the future: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape